# Establecer una comunicación bidireccional entre dos tuberías

Tags: c, ubuntu, pipe

En *C*, debo establecer una comunicación bidireccional entre dos tuberías. A continuación dejo el enunciado del ejercicio:

> Cuando la comunicación entre procesos es simple y ambos extremos de la comunicación han sido generados con un `fork` o pertenecen al mismo proceso, se pueden utilizar tuberías anónimas *(pipes)*.

Las tuberı́as son unidireccionales, por lo que para hacer una comunicación *full-duplex*, se necesitan dos tuberías.

Implementé un programa en *C* que crea un proceso hijo usando la primitiva `fork()`, de forma que el padre y el hijo se comunicarán mediante dos tuberías de la siguiente manera:

- El padre pedirá por pantalla un número entero, y lo enviará a su hijo por la `tubería1`.
- El hijo leerá de la *tubería 1* y obtendrá el entero, calculará si es *par* o *impar*, y enviará por la *tubería 2* la palabra *par* o *impar*, según el cálculo anterior.
- El padre recibirá por la *tubería 2* la palabra *par* o *impar* y lo imprimirá por pantalla.

No olvidar que el padre debe esperar al hijo para una finalización correcta del programa.

Aquí muestro el código que llevo avanzado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <mqueue.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h> //Control de errores
#include <string.h> //Para la funcion strerror()

#define MAX_SIZE    5
#define QUEUE_NAME  "/una_cola"

int main() {
    // Descriptor de la cola
    mqd_t mq;
    // Buffer para la lectura/escritura
    char buffer[MAX_SIZE + 1];
    // Atributos de la cola
    struct mq_attr attr;
    // Resultado de las operaciones
    int resultado;
    // Para realizar el fork
    pid_t rf;
    int flag,status;
    // Variable que guarde el número
    int numero;

    // Inicializar los atributos de la cola. 
    attr.mq_maxmsg = 10;        // Maximo número de mensajes
    attr.mq_msgsize = MAX_SIZE; // Maximo tamaño de un mensaje

    // Realizar el fork
    rf = fork();
    switch (rf){
        // Error
        case -1:
            printf ("No he podido crear el proceso hijo \n");
            exit(1);

        case 0: // Hijo. El hijo solo se encargará de leer.

            /* Apertura de la cola
               O_CREAT: si no existe, se crea
               O_RDWR: lectura/escritura
               O_RDONLY: solo lectura
               O_WRONLY: solo escritura
               0644: permisos rw-r--r--
               attr: estructura con atributos para la cola  */
            mq = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0644, &attr);

            if(mq==-1){
                perror("[HIJO]: Error en la apertura de la cola");
                exit(-1);
            }
            printf ("[HIJO]: mi PID es %d y mi PPID es %d\n", getpid(), getppid());
            printf ("[HIJO]: recibiendo mensaje (espera bloqueante)...\n");

            // Recibimos un mensaje a través de la cola
            resultado = mq_receive(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, NULL);

            if(resultado <= 0){
                perror("[HIJO]: Error al recibir el mensaje");
                exit(-1);           
            }

            // Imprimimos el mensaje recibido
            printf("[HIJO]: el mensaje recibido es \"%s\"\n", buffer);


            // Cerrar la cola
            if(mq_close(mq) == -1){
                perror("[HIJO]: Error cerrando la cola");
                exit(-1);
            }
            break; //Saldría del switch()

        default: // Padre. El padre solo se encargará de escribir

            /* Apertura de la cola */
            mq = mq_open(QUEUE_NAME, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY, 0644, &attr);

            if(mq==-1){
                perror("[PADRE]: Error en la apertura de la cola");
                exit(-1);
            }

            printf ("[PADRE]: mi PID es %d y el PID de mi hijo es %d \n", getpid(), rf);
            /* Rellenamos el buffer que vamos a enviar */   
            printf ("[PADRE]: Introduce un número: ");      
            scanf("%d",&numero);    
            sprintf(buffer,"%d",numero);
            printf("[PADRE]: generado el mensaje \"%s\"\n", buffer);

            // Mandamos el mensaje
            printf("[PADRE]: enviando mensaje...\n");
            resultado = mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0);
            if(resultado == -1){
                perror("[PADRE]: Error al enviar mensaje");
                exit(-1);
            }
            printf("[PADRE]: Mensaje enviado!\n");

            // Cerrar la cola
            if(mq_close(mq) == -1){
                perror("[PADRE]: Error cerrando la cola");
                exit(-1);
            }
            printf("[PADRE]: Cola cerrada.\n");

            // Eliminar la cola
            if(mq_unlink(QUEUE_NAME) == -1){
                perror("[PADRE]: Error eliminando la cola");
                exit(-1);
            }

            /*Espera del padre a los hijos*/
            while ((flag = wait(&status)) > 0){ //Pruebe a sustituir wait() por waitpid()
                if (WIFEXITED(status)){
                    printf("[PADRE]: Hijo con PID %d finalizado, status = %d\n", flag, WEXITSTATUS(status));
                } else if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {  //Para seniales como las de finalizar o matar
                    printf("[PADRE]: Hijo con PID %d finalizado al recibir la señal %d\n", flag, WTERMSIG(status));
                } else if (WIFSTOPPED(status)) { //Para cuando se para un proceso. Al usar wait() en vez de waitpid() no nos sirve.
                    printf("[PADRE]: Hijo con PID %d parado al recibir la señal %d\n", flag,WSTOPSIG(status));
                } else if (WIFCONTINUED(status)){ //Para cuando se reanuda un proceso parado. Al usar wait() en vez de waitpid() no nos sirve.
                    printf("[PADRE]: Hijo con PID %ld reanudado\n",(long int) flag);          
                }
            }
            if (flag==-1 && errno==ECHILD)
                printf("[PADRE]: valor de errno = %d, definido como %s, no hay más hijos que esperar!\n", errno, strerror(errno));
            else
                printf("[PADRE]: Error en la invocacion de wait o la llamada ha sido interrumpida por una señal.\n");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);          
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Aún estoy trabajando en la primera tubería. El problema comienza cuando, durante la ejecución del padre *(default)*, el programa ignora parte del código de éste y pasa directamente a ejecutar el código del hijo.

La parte del código que omite es la siguiente:

```
scanf("%d",&numero);    
sprintf(buffer,"%d",numero);
printf("[PADRE]: generado el mensaje \"%s\"\n", buffer);

// Mandamos el mensaje
printf("[PADRE]: enviando mensaje...\n");
resultado = mq_send(mq, buffer, MAX_SIZE, 0);
if(resultado == -1){
    perror("[PADRE]: Error al enviar mensaje");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("[PADRE]: Mensaje enviado!\n");

// Cerrar la cola
if(mq_close(mq) == -1){
    perror("[PADRE]: Error cerrando la cola");
    exit(-1);
}
printf("[PADRE]: Cola cerrada.\n");
```

Al principio pensé que solo saltaba el `scanf` debido a que el *buffer* del teclado estuviera ocupado, cosa que me extrañaba porque no introduzco nada por teclado con anterioridad. Probé todo tipo de soluciones para que no ignorara el `scanf`, pero me percaté entonces de que no solo ignoraba el `scanf`, sino una parte considerable del código del padre.

A continuación muestro la salida por consola:

> [PADRE]: mi PID es 3672 y el PID de mi hijo es 3673
>   [PADRE]: Introduce un número: [HIJO]: mi PID es 3673 y mi PPID es 3672
>   [HIJO]: recibiendo mensaje (espera bloqueante)...
>   ^C

La ejecución queda en una espera infinita del mensaje (pienso que no le llega al hijo porque no llega a ser enviado por el padre) y tengo que detenerla.

¿Cómo se soluciona esto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te escribo vía respuesta porque lo que pretendo decirte no entra en un comentario.

Estás creando un proceso hijo que se ejecuta en paralelo al padre... no se está omitiendo ningún código. Lo que sucede es lo siguiente:

- Se crea el proceso hijo
- El padre imprime el mensaje: "[PADRE]: mi PID es ..."
- El padre imprime el mensaje: "[PADRE]: introduce un número:"
- El padre se queda esperando el teclado
- El hijo imprime el mensaje: "[HIJO]: mi PID es ..."
- El hijo imprime el mensaje: "[HIJO]: recibiendo mensaje ..."
- El hijo se queda a la espera de que el padre le envíe algo

Al ser dos procesos independientes se ejecutan en paralelo. El programa no se va a comportar como si fuese una ejecución secuencial.

Lo que tienes que hacer es introducir un número y la ejecución debería, en teoría, continuar. Otra cosa que puedes hacer para verificar que la tubería funciona es modificar el código del padre para que le envíe al hijo un número fijo a tu elección (sin pasar por el usuario).